# Adding Session Beans in Spring boot results in No Scope registered for scope 'session'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an issue where I am not able to add session beans in spring boot. In my application.xml I have defined 2 beans with scope as session which I referenced in "leadsJobSchedule" controller as below.

**Application.xml**

```
  <bean id="leadsJobSchedule" class="za.co.discovery.portal.vitality.util.LeadsJobSchedule">
     <property name="leadDetailsMap" ref="leadDetailsMap"/>
     <property name="googleAnalyticsHelper" ref="googleAnalyticsHelper"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="googleAnalyticsHelper" class="za.co.discovery.portal.vitality.util.GoogleAnalyticsHelper" scope="session">
     <property name="readTimeout" value="${timeout.read}" />
     <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${timeout.connect}" />
     <property name="gaTrackingId" value="UA-63460442-1"/>
     <property name="proxyAuthenticator" ref="proxyAuthenticator" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="proxyAuthenticator" class="za.co.discovery.portal.vitality.util.ProxyAuthenticator" scope="session">
    <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxy.host}" />
    <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxy.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${proxy.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${proxy.password}" />
  </bean>
```

**When I start apache in spring boot I get followingerror:**

```
Could not autowire field: private za.co.discovery.portal.vitality.util.GoogleAnalyticsHelper za.co.discovery.portal.vitality.util.LeadsJobSchedule.googleAnalyticsHelper; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'session'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
    at za.co.discovery.portal.vitality.Application.main(Application.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource .
```

Comment: please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first and try asking your question again

Comment: Hi,I have updated the question. Do you know the answer or dint you understand the question?

Comment: i dont know the answer sorry

Comment: No problem. Thank you. I wish someone would help me :)